# Three js - Cannot see object on rotation

Tags: javascript, three.js, rotation, blender

I have a strange problem. I have an object that has been exported from blender to three.js format so i can use it with three.js in my site. I upload it everything is ok. I have also implemented functions to rotate the object with mouse. Now, when i rotate the object i cannot see the bottom.. Here are some pictures.

[image]

[image: Missing bottom]

[image: Blender]

EDIT: Here is the object

```
{
    "name": "CubeGeometry",
    "metadata": {
        "uvs": 1,
        "materials": 1,
        "vertices": 16,
        "version": 3,
        "normals": 8,
        "generator": "io_three",
        "faces": 20,
        "type": "Geometry"
    },
    "normals": [0.717277,0.630238,-0.297098,0.297098,0.630238,0.717277,0.717277,0.630238,0.297098,-0.717277,0.630238,0.297098,-0.297098,0.630238,0.717277,-0.297098,0.630238,-0.717277,-0.717277,0.630238,-0.297098,0.297098,0.630238,-0.717277],
    "uvs": [[0.5,1,0.853553,0.853553,1,0.5,0.853553,0.146447,0.5,0,0.146447,0.146447,0,0.5,0.146447,0.853553,1,0,1,1,0,1,1e-06,0,0,0,1,1]],
    "materials": [{
        "depthTest": true,
        "mapDiffuseAnisotropy": 1,
        "specularCoef": 50,
        "colorAmbient": [0.64,0.64,0.64],
        "blending": "NormalBlending",
        "mapDiffuseRepeat": [1,1],
        "DbgName": "Material",
        "transparent": false,
        "DbgIndex": 0,
        "opacity": 1,
        "mapDiffuseWrap": ["RepeatWrapping","RepeatWrapping"],
        "colorSpecular": [0.5,0.5,0.5],
        "colorDiffuse": [0.64,0.64,0.64],
        "mapDiffuse": "w.jpg",
        "DbgColor": 15658734,
        "colorEmissive": [0,0,0],
        "shading": "smooth",
        "depthWrite": true,
        "visible": true,
        "wireframe": false
    }],
    "vertices": [1.814,0.025002,-1.305,1.9755,0.025002,-1.1435,1.9755,0.025002,1.1435,1.814,0.025002,1.305,-1.814,0.025002,1.305,-1.9755,0.025002,1.1435,-1.9755,0.025002,-1.1435,-1.814,0.025002,-1.305,1.814,-0.024998,-1.305,1.9755,-0.024998,-1.1435,1.9755,-0.024998,1.1435,1.814,-0.024998,1.305,-1.814,-0.024998,1.305,-1.9755,-0.024998,1.1435,-1.9755,-0.024998,-1.1435,-1.814,-0.024998,-1.305],
    "faces": [42,1,3,2,0,0,6,7,0,1,2,42,5,4,3,0,4,5,6,3,4,1,42,7,6,5,0,2,3,4,5,6,3,42,1,0,7,0,0,1,2,0,7,5,42,1,5,3,0,0,4,6,0,3,1,42,1,7,5,0,0,2,4,0,5,3,42,9,11,10,0,0,6,7,0,1,2,42,13,12,11,0,4,5,6,3,4,1,42,15,14,13,0,2,3,4,5,6,3,42,9,8,15,0,0,1,2,0,7,5,42,9,13,11,0,0,4,6,0,3,1,42,9,15,13,0,0,2,4,0,5,3,43,5,13,12,4,0,8,9,10,11,3,3,4,4,43,4,12,11,3,0,12,8,13,10,4,4,1,1,43,3,11,10,2,0,12,8,13,10,1,1,2,2,43,8,0,1,9,0,13,10,12,8,7,7,0,0,43,9,1,2,10,0,12,8,13,10,0,0,2,2,43,7,15,14,6,0,12,8,13,10,5,5,6,6,43,0,8,15,7,0,13,10,12,8,7,7,5,5,43,6,14,13,5,0,12,8,13,10,6,6,3,3]
}
```

Comment: Is there a material applied to the bottom of the object? It's either that or the normals are missing/bad. Try visualizing them to see what direction they point. http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Extras.Helpers/FaceNormalsHelper

Comment: @JCD I did not understand much from the link you gave me. I added the edges and they where some green lines going up and on the sides, no bottom though. I updated my question with the json object. Thank you for your time! :)

Comment: What happens if you add `object.material.side = THREE.DoubleSide`?

Comment: @WestLangley I cannot see my material at all :p

Comment: Most likely your model is incorrect. The winding order of each face must be counter-clockwise. I expect you want your vertex normals to be perpendicular to the faces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i had to do was to select the face i was not able to see and then on edit mode, go to mesh -> faces -> flip normals